# Laravel update the status in other foreign key table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have three tables (users, table_1, table_2) and have users table foreign keys in table_1 & table_2 tables.

**Users**

```
id
name
email
status (1/0)
created_at
updated_at
```

**Table 1**

```
id
message
status (1/0)
user_id (FK of users)
created_at
updated_at
```

**Table 2**

```
id
about
status (1/0)
user_id (FK of users)
created_at
updated_at
```

> Note: For the explanation, I have used Table 1,2 name.

Now I am updating the status of the user table and the same status update in table_1 & table_2 where the foreign key is a match.

Here I have written individual query for each table:

```
$users = Users::where('id', $id)->update([
    'status' => $status
]);

Table1::where('user_id', $id)->update([
    'status' => $status
]);

Table2::where('user_id', $id)->update([
    'status' => $status
]);
```

So is there any way to reduce the query with the eloquent relationship?

Comment: You want smth like this ? `$user = Users::find($id);

$user->status = $status;
$user->table1->status = $status;
$user->table1->status = $status;

$user->save();`

Comment: @FatimaMazhit Yes. Thanks. I will try it out.

Comment: Why you are saving same status in different tables. Ideally you should only save it in users table and if you have proper relations with table_1 and table_2 you can access them as - table_1->user->status or table_2->user->status

Comment: It's developed by other developers.

Comment: If you are using mysql and you do not want to perform these operations with laravel, you can create a trigger.